# Shift of origin

Tags: coordinate-systems

Why do we subtract when we shift the origin?

So, the way i understand, shifting the origin by (2,2) means moving the entire coordinate system. Therefore, the point (0,0) in the original coordinate system should be at (2,2) in the new coordinate system, right?

To have the point (0,0) at (2,2) in the new coordinate system, you should add 2 to the x-coordinate and 2 to the y-coordinate of the original point. This is because you are moving the point from (0,0) to (2,2), which involves adding values, not subtraction.

perhaps the answer is obvious but i don't have math background. just trynna make sense

Comment: Considering one dimension is sufficient. When the points in the two systems are related by $x'=x+s$ then the functions $x'\mapsto f(x'-s)$ and $x\mapsto f(x)$ assign same values to corresponding points $x'$ and $x\,.$

Comment: More explanation in [active and passive transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_and_passive_transformation).

Comment: Distinguish between the coordinate system and points. In the original coordinate system, say person $A$ is at $(0,0)$ and person $B$ is at $(2,2)$, i.e. coordinates are relative to person $A$. Then after your passive transformation, the new coordinates are relative to person $B$. Person $A$ is at $(-2,-2)$ relative to person $B$.